# Generalizing a searching method between ArrayLists of classes

Tags: java

I have a four classes `Book Disk Paper Magazine` all of them derive from another class `Items` and all of them have a `String barcode` field.

In another class `foo` I have `ArrayList<Book> books; ArrayList<Disk> disks; ArrayList<Paper> papers; ArrayList<Magazine> magazines;`, and I want to implement for each one of these a `getByBarcode(String barcode)` method, that would look in the arraylist for the item with that barcode. If it's a book it has to look in the books list etc.

Can I avoid having to do four different ones? What I mean is avoiding having to do a `getBookByBarcode(String barcode)` that would have to look in the books list, `getDiskByBarcode(String barcode)` that would have to look in the disks list etc..

And have a generic one like `public Object getByBarcode(String barcode,type)`. How do I do this nicely in an OOP way?

Comment: `T getByBarCode(List<T extends Items> items, String barCode)`

The signature should say it all.

Comment: Yes but the `getByBarCode` function will be called from outside `foo`, and the other class calling it doesn't have access to the item lists

Comment: If so, use the four methods you wanted to avoid. Keep it simple.

Comment: You could also use an enum with the values `BOOK`, `DISK` and so on and you can provide one of these value to the `getByBarcode(String, WhereEnum)` method. Inside that method, you could use a switch statement to determine the list to search for the barcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially every Book, Magazine, Disk & Paper is an Item. Hence you should have a parent class named Item and **not** its plural form. Every Base Class should classify as a singular entity.

You should then create objects of Book, Magazine, Disk & Paper. Since all of these classify as an Item, create an **array list of type Item** and add these objects to the same.

This way you have a item list which has books, magazines, disks & papers. You can then look into this list for an item with barcode and get the type of item.

Source Code:

**Item.java**

```
package myLibrary;

public class Item {

    protected String barcode;

    public String getBarcode() {
        return barcode;
    }

    public void setBarcode(String barcode) {
        this.barcode = barcode;
    }

    public Item(String barcode) {
        this.barcode = barcode;
    }
}
```

**Book.java / Disk.java / Magazine.java / Paper.java**

```
package myLibrary;

public class Book extends Item {

    public Book(String barcode) {
        super(barcode);
    }

    public String getBarcode() {
        return barcode;
    }


}
```

**Lecturer.java (Class containing main function)**

```
package myCollege;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import myLibrary.Book;
import myLibrary.Disk;
import myLibrary.Item;
import myLibrary.Magazine;
import myLibrary.Paper;

public class Lecturer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Declare items
        Book x1 = new Book("Item101");
        Book x2 = new Book("Item102");
        Disk x3 = new Disk("Item201");
        Disk x4 = new Disk("Item202");
        Magazine x5 = new Magazine("Item301");
        Paper x6 = new Paper("Item401");
        Paper x7 = new Paper("Item402");

        ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
        items.add(x1);
        items.add(x2);
        items.add(x3);
        items.add(x4);
        items.add(x5);
        items.add(x6);
        items.add(x7);

        String itemType = getItemByBarcode("Item202", items);
        System.out.println(itemType);


    }

    private static String getItemByBarcode(String barcode, ArrayList<Item> items) {
        String itemType = "";
        for(Item i : items) {
            if(i.getBarcode().equalsIgnoreCase(barcode)) {
                itemType = i.getClass().getSimpleName();                
            }
        }
        return itemType;
    }

}
```

**Output:**

```
Disk
```

I hope this helps in better understanding of the concept/issue.

Comment: I don't see the value added by the generics on `Item` or `Lecturer`.

Comment: Edited them out as they are not required in this case. Thank you for the review comment Makoto.

Answer (score 1):

may sound hackish but you can do like some other users suggested and call

```
public Object getByBarcode(String barcode, Class<T> classy)
{
   ArrayList<Items> items = null;
   if(classy.class.getSimpleName().equals(Book.class.getSimpleName()))
       items = bookArray;
   else if(classy.class.getSimpleName().equals(Magazine.class.getSimpleName()))
       items = magazineArray;
   else 
       ... cnt'd  


   for(Item i : items) 
       if( i.getBarCode().equals(barcode) return i;
}
```

Then to call this beastly mess you could do something like . . .

```
Item i = getByBarCode("0932A3", Book.class);
```